# Obtain data from a API by setting the path variable in the API Link

Tags: python, json, api, import, path

I am trying to retrieve data from a API. 
Given is the link of API used:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/8854915/SzS7R6uu?version=latest

---

I wish to obtain data from: "https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries/:country" where "country" is a variable, to get the data for any respective country.
Here is my approach to the problem:

```
country = "Zimbabwe"
all_cases = requests.get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries/<str:country>')
all_cases_json = all_cases.json()
print(all_cases_json)
```

And it doesn't work thereby giving an output:

```
{'message': "Country not found or doesn't have any cases"}
```

How do I retrieve the desired data?

Answer (score 0):

To get the data for a specific country the API URL is;

https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/Zimbabwe

Comment: This is a link only answer, this should a comment instead of an answer

Answer (score 0):

use iso2 or iso3 while importing all the countries. iso2 is like the US for America or PK for Pakistan,
When you try to pull up the information regarding a specific country. the API will give you a response by its corresponding Country using iso2 and iso3 Format so in this case, it might be a zim

Answer (score 0):

Like Tebogo said above, the API URL is [https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/{country_name}](https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/%7Bcountry_name%7D).
With that information, you should use an f string to access the URL with the requests module.

```
# country = "Zimbabwe"
cases_raw = requests.get(f'https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/{country}')
cases_json = cases_raw.json()
print(f'Cases JSON: {cases_json}')
```